# Books/resources for statistical field theory

Tags: statistical-mechanics, resource-recommendations, renormalization, ising-model, critical-phenomena

I was wondering if anyone knows good, approachable textbook or other resources about statistical field theory (topics like in Kardar's Statistical physics of fields: lattice models, mean field theory, Landau-Ginzburg, renormalizations, critical phenomena etc). I am looking for something really basic, all books I was able to find were way too advances and did not have enough examples and explanations for someone who is not in the field but needs to understand more advanced concepts.

Comment: Introduction to Statistical Field Theory by Edouard Brézin seems very good. I am planning to go through it soon.

Comment: I would recommend also "Lectures On Phase Transitions And The Renormalization Group" by Nigel Goldenfeld.  It's not a book on statistical field theory, but I found that the main difficulty I had for statistical field theory books was usually renormalization.