# Functional Integrals in statistical field theory

Tags: statistical-mechanics, field-theory, resource-recommendations, education

I've been reading Kardar's statistical fields book where there are many functional integrals.
In the book he gave the definition as a product of integrals but to me it was not enough to really understand how to actually do it.

I've been looking online for a working example of one but the closest thing I could find was with many skipped steps and $\propto$ followed by some argument.

Could anyone refer me to a source that have what I'm looking for? I feel like I just need to see it once from top to bottom to clear my head

Comment: Please be specific about your question before it is labeled as off-topic.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/164503/2451 and links therein.